# Building data with logic

Tags: haskell

I have a data type like this:

```
data FooBar =
  FooBar { foo :: Double
         , bar :: Double
         , ter :: Double
         }

-- hypothetical builder with some random logic
mkFooBar :: Double -> Double -> FooBar
mkFooBar a b
  | a < 5     = FooBar a b (a + b)
  | a > 100   = FooBar a b (a * b)
  | otherwise = FooBar (a ^ 2) (b ^ 2) ((a + b) ^2)
```

and some predefined values used around the program like:

```
fBLess5 = mkFooBar 1 200
fBMore100 = mkFooBar 200 200
fBSquared = mkFooBar 50 200
-- and so on
```

Is it ok building predefined values like that in Haskell? If `fBLess5` is used N-times around the program, it will be built N-times if it is written in that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work. By binding the value to a name, you ensure that it is only evaluated (at most) once and then shared, no matter how often you use it.

(There is an exception, though:

```
foo :: (Num a) => a
foo = 42
```

This apparent constant is polymorphic and will be recomputed at each use (it's really `fromInteger (42 :: Integer)`). But that doesn't apply to your code, which is all monomorphic.)

Comment: ok thank you - so I didn't write any sort of blasphemy :) or "bad practice" for that specific case, right?

Comment: @Randomize No, I don't see a problem with your code.

Comment: @Randomize No, using top-level bindings for things which should be computed only once is fairly idiomatic.

Comment: To be clear, these statements are about how GHC works now (and even then they aren't absolute).  Nothing in the Haskell Report says anything about how often any expression is evaluated.